# How do you make a belongs_to required with mongo mapper?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I am using [Mongo Mapper](http://mongomapper.com/) and I'm trying to figure out how you make a document required.  For example, I want to do something like this:

```
class Question
  include MongoMapper::Document

  many :answers
end

class Answer
  include MongoMapper::Document

  belongs_to :question, :required => true
end
```

But when I do, it's doesn't enforce that the answer have a question:

```
> Answer.new.save
 => true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoMapper includes ActiveModel::Validations so you can use validations just like active record. The following should work:

```
class Question
  include MongoMapper::Document

  many :answers
end

class Answer
  include MongoMapper::Document

  belongs_to :question

  validates :question, :presence => true
end
```

You can check the rails docs for more info on those validations here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

Answer (score 0):

What about some callbacks?

```
class Answer
  include MongoMapper::Document

  belongs_to :question

  def before_save
    # if question is nil, return false (this cancels save)
    return false unless question
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: There's really not something built into MongoMapper to handle this though?

Comment: MongoMapper supports ActiveRecord-like callbacks. Try it.